# Unit Test project not adding command-line arguments

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I've added two command line arguments to the Unit Test Project, let's say they are `foo` and `bar`.

When I debug the Unit Test, `var args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` is holding 11 arguments, and ignoring the two I set.

How can I stop the 11 arguments being added and just use my own? Or even append mine to the 11?

Here are the args it is putting in:
[image: command line args]

Comment: How are you starting/ running the Unit Test project

Comment: By clicking "Debug" under my [TestMethod]

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - unit tests aren't run in the context of your normal application, and arguably whatever it is you're testing that needs to get hold of the command line arguments isn't decoupled enough - if the code needs parameters, the unit test should probably supply them directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will use a .runsettings file as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2019). Azure Devops will then be able to supply parameters in pipeline.